# Process Changing on Demand Resources asset packs hosted by Apple

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to evaluate the advantages of using On Demand Resources , rather than hosting the images on my own server.

I am reading through [On Demand Resources Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH2-SW1) and cannot find references to how these can be changed after submission. Assuming this is for the Appstore and the asset packs are hosted on iTunes

Should I want to change my images that after my app has been approved, would this involve a new version and a new submission or could I change these quickly without involving a lengthy review process and a version change.

Comment: We can host on demand asset packs on apple server as given in the documentation. The process of including the on demand resources in server is given in the documentation.

Comment: The following are links for that.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/GeneratingHostedContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH19-SW1
I only did a quick look through the documentation. But, I believe a new version or submission is not required for your hosted assets. You can update those assets from AppStore Server

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri I have gone through the documentation a few times and cannot find any reference to whether a new version is needed or not. I acknowledge that the documentation shows how to include assets initially, but not how they are changed.

Comment: From what I learned from lecture (WWDC 2015 session 214), I believe you can't change your assets without a new version or new submission. The reason for this is because, it is mentioned in the lecture that you can upload these on-demand resources to Xcode/AppStore server only when you upload your app to AppStore (This comment became too long, so I wrote my explanation is in the answer section. Please suggest edits so that I can make it better).

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have already gone through the WWDC 2015 session 214. According to that, we can only host the content on Xcode server/ App Store/ Xcode/ TestFlight/ Enterprise Deployment. It is mentioned that it is part of AppThinning. You are supposed to add images and add tags to them in Assets section itself (you are supposed to click on attribute inspector for asset and assign On-Demand Resource Tag). Then, when you upload your app to AppStore, Xcode will host those tagged for on-demand resource on server. That means, when you download and install your application from appstore, the on-demand resource tagged assets which are a part of "Download Only On Demand" will not be part of the app. You use api to fetch them from server.

I have just gone through the following sections of developer documentation on On-Demand-Resources. We can host the asset packs on a personal server apart from AppStore that comply with the Apple app transport security requirements in distribution version only when it's an enterprise app.

*The following is given in the documentation*

> *Apps distributed through the App Store can retrieve on-demand resources from your own web server during development and testing, but must use Apple's hosting when published on the App Store. Enterprise apps using in-house distribution can retrieve on-demand resources from your own web server during both development and distribution.*

So, if you are making an enterprise app that's not distributed through App Store. Then, you can change your On Demand Resources without making another binary. If your app is distributed through App Store, then the assets should be hosted on Apple's hosting. I'm not sure whether you can change your assets on Apple's hosting(AppStore) or not since there's no method given on how to upload assets packs on AppStore in the official documentation or WWDC session. But, there is a method given on how to upload your assets packs to your own server here.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/GeneratingHostedContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH19-SW1

*Resources:*

> https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-on-demand-resources-on-ios-and-tvos--cms-24929
>
> https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/214/
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/EnablingHosting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH18-SW1
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/IntrotoHostingODR.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH17-SW1

Please suggest any edits required

Comment: Docs say: You can host on-demand resources for your app on any compliant web server. Apps distributed through the App Store can retrieve on-demand resources from your own web server during development and testing, but **must** use Apple's hosting when published on the App Store.

Comment: I have watched WWDC , I will look again try find the part where they say "**only** when you upload your app to AppStore" , perhaps you could give me a precise minute second, when they mention this.

Comment: In the **Resource Tags** section you can move by dragging a tag you defined to a section called **Initial Install Tags** These are supposed to be installed at install time. You said  ***"That means, when you download and install your application from appstore, the on-demand resource tagged assets will not be part of the app"*** is not correct for this case.

Comment: @Ryan Heitner, I'm sorry. It looks like we can change it in the server. I have gone through the WWDC lecture/lecture slides again. It looks like I got confused by looking at slide number 70. I just checked the developer documentation page for ODR (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/EnablingHosting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH18-SW1). Here, it's mentioned about how you can host and retrieve ODR on a personal server. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, because the resources are embedded in the Xcode project and not in iTunes connect, the only way you can change the resources is by submitting a new binary. 
I'll add that if the new version of your app only includes updated on-demande resources, I guess it will take less time for your app to be reviewed.

Comment: The resources are not always embedded , you can choose to have them embedded for convenience. You can separate them from the IPA